# How to open a PDF file on click?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I have a button like below which in charge of opening an image in top of the ASP.NET application.

```html
<asp:Button 
    ID="MatrixButton" 
    runat="server" 
    Text="Risk Matrix" 
    CausesValidation="False"
    OnClientClick="openImageDoc('Images/RiskMatrixCapitalAllocation.jpg', 'RiskMatrix')"/>
```

Now I need to have another button to do the same function but this time opens a PDF file

```html
<asp:Button 
    ID="AnalysisButton" 
    runat="server" 
    Text="Risk Analysis" 
    CausesValidation="False"
    OnClientClick="openPDFDoc('PDF/RiskAnalysis.pdf.jpg', 'RiskAnalysis')"/>
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```js
 function openPDFDoc(filePath, titleName) {
    var newUrl = baseUrl + filePath;
    window.open(newUrl, titleName, 'width=900,height=800,scrollbars=1');
}
```

Comment: `PDF/RiskAnalysis.pdf.jpg` is not a PDF file, and you haven't showed us what the `openPDFDoc` code even does. We need to know what error you're getting (opening your "Network" panel in Chrome will tell you if the server is responding with a 404 or 500), what you expect to happen, and what is happening.

Comment: Ok , thanks I added the function I was doing a silly mistake on calling the PDF name, thanks by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the extension `.jpg` from the path.

Replace This:

```
PDF/RiskAnalysis.pdf.jpg
```

With This:

```
PDF/RiskAnalysis.pdf
```